# Passing argument 2 of "write" makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, linux

```
char name[] = "Name123";   //string
write(2, name[strlen(name)-1], 1);    //required to write 3 to terminal
```

After compiling the above code, a warning is returned saying passing argument 2 of "write" makes pointer from integer without a cast. Upon running, I do not get an output. Can someone teach me how to access a character in the string of an index of my choice and write it into terminal using 'write()' only.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/ is a site which contains documentation. Used mostly for C++, but it also has C documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` expects a pointer. Add `&` to pass the *address* of `3`.

```
write(2, &name[strlen(name)-1], 1);
```

Comment: `write(2, name+strlen(name)-1, 1);` would also do